# I want to select some variables from a df, but I need them to be "unhardcoded"

Tags: r, dplyr

So, from the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
data_all_month <- select(data_all_month, site, eoicode, no2, month, year, date)
data_all_year <- select(data_all_year, site, eoicode, no2, year)
```

I want to `select` some columns from the `df` but my main problem is that I would like the variables that I select to not being hard coded, so I can change them with the parameter I want and depending the one that I'd like. E.g. I'm analysing some values of `no2` but in another moment I would like to do it for the `o3` column.

I've tried the code:

```r
data_all_month <- select(data_all_month, site, eoicode, no2, month, year, date)
data_all_year <- select(data_all_year, site, eoicode, no2, year)
```

Comment: The down vote is probably due to the missing reproducibility of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example I think it is fairly easy, but difficult to tell without having a reproducible question containing expected output: `df = mtcars; cols_to_select = names(df)[1:3]; dplyr::select(df, dplyr::all_of(cols_to_select))`, where I have specified the columns of interest as a chracter vector called `cols_to_select`.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for not being very specific, I'm quite new here so it's hard for me to express my questions and the way to do it...

Comment: As I mentioned, start off by reading the linked thread.

Comment: Selection-helpers are fairly simple, as said by @Friede. But, unlike `dplyr::all_of`. `dplyr::any_of` will not check for missing columns.